# Pycharm Python Selenium driver.switch_to.default_content() and request.clsdriver = driver syntax

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

When running the following code, I receive a syntax error, but can't figure why:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    global driver
    browser_name=request.config.getoption("browser_name")
    if browser_name == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\geckodriver.exe")
    elif browser_name == "IE":
        print("IE driver")

    driver.get("https://ign.com/wikis/")


    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='__tcfapiLocator']")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(#_evidon-banner-acceptbutton).click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()
```

---

Syntax error is as follows:

```
ImportError while loading conftest 'U:\test\conftest.py'.
C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\ast.py:50: in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
E     File "U:\test\conftest.py", line 38
E       request.cls.driver = driver
E       ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 4

Empty suite
```

---

If I comment out the iframe  sections, this test runs without issue

I'm guessing this is a 'can't see the woods for the trees' scenario

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Invalid syntax" typically means you are missing punctuation or breaking some syntax rule. To find the problem, start where the error is shown and work backwards. Let's look at the previous few lines prior to the one that reports the syntax error:

```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(#_evidon-banner-acceptbutton).click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    request.cls.driver = driver
```

The syntax highlighting from Stack Overflow provides a clue to the problem. You can see that `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(` is in white while `#_evidon-banner-acceptbutton).click()` is gray. Gray indicates a comment that starts with `#`.

I assume that you mean `#_evidon-banner-acceptbutton` to be the CSS selector. To fix the problem, you need to make this a string by surrounding it with quotes:

```
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#_evidon-banner-acceptbutton").click()
```

Notice how the `"#_evidon-banner-acceptbutton"` is green now because the surrounding `""`s indicate it is a string.

I strongly suggest that you enable syntax highlighting in your editor to help find problems like these on your own.

Comment: I'm sorry there is no some kind of "great upvote" here :)

Comment: @Prophet  :What so special about this answer ? He has written the same thing what I have written below, do we really need those explanation for just double quote issue.

Comment: Sometimes do. Simply without the quotes / double quotes one would have a syntax error on `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(#_evidon-banner-acceptbutton).click()` line itself. But since there is a `#` there Python interpreted it as beginning of comment block.

Comment: @cruisepandey Your answer is good. I felt like teaching the OP how to fish rather than just catching this one fish for them.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are not using double quotes at this line :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(#_evidon-banner-acceptbutton).click()
```

instead use this :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#_evidon-banner-acceptbutton").click()
```

Comment: thankyou all for your comments and helpful answers, much appreciated!